# cucumber @before Background and scenario

Tags: java, gradle, cucumber

ok, I am new to cucumber ...
I am trying to write some test defs for the features written by my teacher (uni)
ahm I have to use @before where I have to create a new Object of bank, and then whenever I run the scenario it creates a new bank object for me ...
everything was ok until I got the background in the features ... so the feature look like this ...

```
>   Background: 
>     Given Ali is a customer
>     And Ali opens a current account with account number 4566
>     And Ali opens a current account with account number 8979
> 
>   Scenario: Deposits are logged in transaction logs
>     Given £29.99 is deposited into account 4566
>      When £9.01 is deposited into account 4566
>      Then Account 4566 has 2 transactions
```

now I create a new bank I run the background steps, and then when we reach the scenario @Before jumps in and it creates the new bank here is its code ...
@Before

```
 public void beforeScenario() {
        bank = new Bank();
    }
```

so when i reach scenario and try to access the objects that i created through background i get a null pointer here is the cucumber result ..

```
 Background:                                                # All_transactions_are_logged.feature:7
    Given Ali is a customer                                  # StepDefs.is_a_customer(String)
    And Ali opens a current account with account number 4566 # StepDefs.opens_a_current_account_with_account_number(String,int)
    And Ali opens a current account with account number 8979 # StepDefs.opens_a_current_account_with_account_number(String,int)

  Scenario: Deposits are logged in transaction logs # All_transactions_are_logged.feature:12
    Given ú29.99 is deposited into account 4566     # StepDefs.is_deposited_into_account(String,long)
      java.lang.NullPointerException
        at my.bank.Account.deposit(Account.java:133)
        at my.bank.StepDefs.is_deposited_into_account(StepDefs.java:73)
        at ?.Given ú29.99 is deposited into account 4566(All_transactions_are_logged.feature:13)

    When ú9.01 is deposited into account 4566       # StepDefs.is_deposited_into_account(String,long)
    Then Account 4566 has 2 transactions
```

Any suggestion is helpfull ... 
Please

Comment: Can you add the code in Account.java from where this NPE is originating?